# How can I set VS Code color scheme in Rider?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rider

I switched from VS to Rider recently, and would like to use VS Code or Visual Studio color scheme in Rider. How can I set that? Rider has Visual Studio color scheme but it's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Rider, if you open up File > Settings... and then choose Editor > Color Scheme then you can create your own scheme. You can select an existing one and then clone it from the cogwheel menu. Perhaps one of the Visual Studio themes would be a good starting point for you.